# Understanding Zustand with Laravel validation errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to understand and implement Zustand in my NextJS app, I have a Laravel endpoint that logs a user in. If there are validation errors it sends JSON back formatted like so:

```json
{
    "message": "The email field is required. (and 1 more error)",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ],
        "password": [
            "The password field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

or

```json
{
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "Invalid Credentials"
        ]
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is display the errors on my Next.js login form under the form input fields.

My login form is as follows:

```js
export default Login

function Login() {
    const userService = useUserService()

    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()

    async function onSubmit({ email, password }) {
        await userService.login(email, password)
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-8">
                <div>
                    <label
                        htmlFor="email"
                        className="mb-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                    >
                        Email address
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        { ...register("email") }
                        className="block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-blue-500 focus:bg-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                    />
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.email?.message?.toString()}</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label
                        htmlFor="password"
                        className="mb-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
                    >
                        Password
                    </label>
                    <input
                        { ...register("password") }
                        type="password"
                        className="block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-blue-500 focus:bg-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                    />
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">{errors.password?.message?.toString()}</div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button
                        disabled={formState.isSubmitting}
                        className={"w-full group inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md py-2 px-4 text-sm font-semibold focus:outline-none focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 bg-blue-600 text-white hover:text-slate-100 hover:bg-blue-500 active:bg-blue-800 active:text-blue-100 focus-visible:outline-blue-600 " + (formState.isSubmitting ? ButtonSpinner['btn-loading'] : "")}
                    >
                        <span>Sign in <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

In my `userService.login` function I have the following:

```
import { create } from 'zustand'
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

import { useAlertService } from './useAlertService'
import { useFetch } from '../_helpers/client'

export { useUserService }

const initialState = {
    users: undefined,
    user: undefined,
    currentUser: undefined
}

const userStore = create(() => initialState)

function useUserService() {
    const alertService = useAlertService()
    const fetch = useFetch()
    const router = useRouter()
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const { users, user, currentUser } = userStore()

    return {
        users,
        user,
        currentUser,
        login: async (email, password) => {
            alertService.clear()

            try {
                const currentUser = await fetch.post('/api/authentication/token', {email, password})
                userStore.setState({ ...initialState, currentUser })

                const returnUrl = searchParams.get('returnUrl') || '/dashboard'

                router.push(returnUrl)
            } catch (error) {
                alertService.error(error)
            }
        },
    }
}
```

Also, in the `alertService.error` I have:

```js
import { create } from 'zustand'

export { useAlertService }

const alertStore = create(() => ({}))

function useAlertService() {
    const { alert } = alertStore()

    return {
        alert,
        error: (message, showAfterRedirect = false) => {
            const type = 'alert-danger';
            alertStore.setState({
                alert: { type, message, showAfterRedirect }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If I console log the `message` it just gives me the error `The email field is required. (and 1 more error)` or `Invalid Credentials` based on the error that comes back ... But I need it to display the errors, the `email` or `password` field needs to be the field that it displays under and I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are loging the `message` where? You do not seem to have called `useAlertService` in `Login`.

Comment: useAlertService comes from useUserService and returns in the try catch `alertService.error(error)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `useAlertService` hook inside `Login`. Grab the `alert` state and use it like below (notice the comments):

```js
export default Login;

function Login() {
  const userService = useUserService();
  const { alert } = useAlertService(); // Line I add
  console.log(alert); // Check the type of data you are getting here, and adapt what I have done below
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  async function onSubmit({ email, password }) {
    await userService.login(email, password);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="mt-10 grid grid-cols-1 gap-y-8">
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email" className="mb-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
            Email address
          </label>
          <input
            type="email"
            {...register("email")}
            className="block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-blue-500 focus:bg-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
          />
          {/* Line I changed */}
          {alert?.message?.errors?.email && (
            <div className="invalid-feedback">{alert.message.errors.email[0]}</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password" className="mb-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
            Password
          </label>
          <input
            {...register("password")}
            type="password"
            className="block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-200 bg-gray-50 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-400 focus:border-blue-500 focus:bg-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
          />
          {/* Line I changed */}
          {alert?.message?.errors?.password && (
            <div className="invalid-feedback">{alert.message.errors.password[0]}</div>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button
            disabled={formState.isSubmitting}
            className={
              "w-full group inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md py-2 px-4 text-sm font-semibold focus:outline-none focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 bg-blue-600 text-white hover:text-slate-100 hover:bg-blue-500 active:bg-blue-800 active:text-blue-100 focus-visible:outline-blue-600 " +
              (formState.isSubmitting ? ButtonSpinner["btn-loading"] : "")
            }
          >
            <span>
              Sign in <span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>
            </span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```